# Pandas.dataframe.plot Reduce ticks on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas data frame for which I have created a plot.

[image]

As you can see the x-axis contains month labels but there are extra ticks...
Can anyone tell me how to remove the extra x ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'])
```